# Split app name at a predetermined point if it doesn't fit one line?

Tags: android

My android app name is too long for my phone to display in one line, so the last character gets moved to the next line on the home screen. I'd like to have the split occur 3 characters earlier however, as it would make more sense for the name in question.

I could introduce a whitespace at the point where I want the name to be split, however that would mean that on phones where the whole name fits one line, the whitespace would show up.

Is there a way to predetermine a splitting point for the app name, so that android splits the name at that point if necessary?

Comment: Have you considered changing the name?  If its that long, it really isn't user friendly.

Comment: Yes I have, but I'd rather stick with the current name if it's possible.

Comment: can you add line break \n?

Comment: @whiterabbitj I tried it and it doesn't. The line brake gets displayed as a whitespace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get the desired behaviour by adding a zero-width white space character (`&#8203;`) where I want the name to be split. During my tests, if the name fits one line, it gets displayed without a visible white space, while if it doesn't fit, it gets cut where I added the zero-width white space.

Edit: A soft hyphen (`&#173;`) works too, as it adds a hyphen if the name is split.

Use at your own risk!

Comment: I'd really recommend you get a shorter app name. This kind of hack is very likely to have an unexpected behavior on some Android implementation, while a short name won't ever cause any trouble.

Comment: I tested it on multiple devices, and since it's a personal project anyway, I do not mind any unexpected behaviour that could maybe with some configuration happen.